# Flutter: Provider Value Not Updating

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I am new to flutter/dart and am trying to get a value to update for a loading bar I would like to make. The value is updating within a provider widget I created, but when I try to utilize it, I am unable to figure out what is missing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
class LoadingProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _downloadPercentage = 0;
  int get downloadPercentage => _downloadPercentage;

  void getPercentage(int input) {
    _downloadPercentage = input;
    notifyListeners();
    print(downloadPercentage);
  }

}
```

Here is the page I wish to display on

```
class ContourScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Note note;
  ContourScreen(this.note);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ContourScreenState();
}

class _ContourScreenState extends State<ContourScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
   final loadingProvider = Provider.of<LoadingProvider>(context);
    return  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(),
        
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(

            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                 
                  ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<int>>(
                      create: (context) => ValueNotifier<int>(0),
                  child: Text('${loadingProvider.downloadPercentage}'),),
              

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the git hub to all pages for reference https://github.com/mattcubs/loadinggif

Comment: How is `ContourScreen` used? Is it used as a descendent of `ChangeNotifierProvider<LoadingProvider>`? Are you certain you updated the value correctly, i.e., really called `getPercentage`? Your github repo doesn't contain those details.

Comment: Sorry if I do not fully understand your comment. The only place getPercentage is utilized is on line 249 on gif_image_widget. I will also add the containing page for my ContourScreen to the github